# Opening Spyder appear a command window that does not closes itself

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

Today I have updated Anaconda Navigator to version 2.0.1 using this command: `conda update --all`.
Now, when I try to open Spyder (version 5.0.0), to work in Python, it opens and works correctly, but a command screen appears and it's idles with the cursor blinking.

It is supposed that the command window should closes itself, but I have waited for 1 hour and the command window still it is there.

Below you will find a screen shot:

[image: command_window]

The file `spyder-out-1.txt` it is blank (With no information inside).

The file `spyder-err-1.txt` have this: **No QCoreApplication instance found. Application patches not applied. You have to call load_stylesheet function after instantiation of QApplication to take effect.**

I use:
Anaconda 2.0.1, Spyder 5.0.0, Windows 10

I guess that this is an error, so, please provide me some information in order to avoid this malfunction.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try updating your Spyder to 5.0.1 which is the latest release and fixed a lot of bugs

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your question. In general, you should [edit] the question to *clarify* it, but not to include an answer within it. You should create your own answer with the code/solution you used to solve your problem, and then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to doing so). When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).